# Fusion Charts - controlling margins, padding, etc

Tags: fusioncharts

As you can see in this screenshot, I'm having some issues with the margins/padding.  For example, the top of the trend line is being covered up by top of chart area. Ditto with bottom.  And there's not enough space between the data point areas.

[image]

See: http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/contents/ChartSS/ScrollArea2D.html#Anchor3

Here's a snippet of my existing config:

```
xml += "xAxisName='Bets' yAxisName='Chips' canvasPadding='30' formatNumberScale='0' "
xml += "toolTipBorderColor='951818' numVisiblePlot='7' showLegend='0' scrollHeight='15' scrollBtnWidth='14' "
xml += "chartBottomMargin='5' chartTopMargin='3' chartLeftMargin='2' chartRightMargin='10' "
xml += "xAxisNamePadding='0' yAxisNamePadding='2' captionPadding='3'>"
xml += "yAxisValuesPadding='0'>"
```

I can paste the whole thing, if need be.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire XML with sample data that exhibits this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the upper and the lower limit of the chart is same as the value of trendlines. Hence this overlapping. In scroll chart you can not put trendlines above the canvas border.